# Get bit stream from known radio frequency

Tags: c#, fft

I'm a beginner in radio demodulation, and several days can't solve my problem. The problem is to get bit stream from known frequency.
I made I C# application that gets the data in real time from FunCube dongle and applies FFT. But what to do next - it is a puzzle for me. 
The final goal is to detect narrow-band signal on a known frequency and get the bit stream from it.
I've already read different books on DSP but I'm at an impasse.
So, the question is what to read, where to go, maybe any algorithms.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What does it mean to get a "bit stream from known radio frequency"?

Comment: I have a radio device that sends data. I know the frequency and I want to get this data.I wrote a C# program that uses the FunCube as microfon input, and the aim is to get the data from the known frequency. Maybe my description is not good but I`m just start with it.

Comment: Are you saying that you've modulated a signal, fed it to your dongle, gotten the output from your dongle, and now you want to demodulate it and see that you've recovered your original signal?

Comment: Yes, that`s it.

Comment: So you're asking us how to demodulate your signal without telling us what modulation scheme you're using?

Comment: I ask what to read and what to do to understand how to make it by myself.

Comment: @Valeriy  Can you tell us anything about the signal?

Comment: I just want to get the data from theis signal (I want to learn how to get the data from radio). I wrote an application for listening mic input, make FFT with the income data - but what to do next - I don`t know. 
The aim of the project is to make a transmitter (as a hardware) that send narrow signal and to make a program for Windows that will use the mic input and gets the data from the trasmitter. The aim is to send the signal for 5-10 km distance.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20433271/the%20signal%20to%20detect.png
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20433271/the%20signal%20to%20detect%202.png
The pictures.

Comment: And really I don`t know anything about the signal modulation scheme. But I really very interested to understand how to demodulete the signals - and what modulation should I use for my project.

Comment: Does this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation